# angular no access to object.id

Tags: html, angular, typescript

hey i just started with angular and my problem is, why i have no access to my .id,.name and .color, the first code is my oberteile-names.ts where i have defined my const array

```
import { Oberteil } from './oberteile/oberteil';

export const OBERTEILE: Oberteil[] = [
    {id:11, name: 'flannelshirt', color: 'vintagebrown'},
    {id:12, name: 'flannelshirt', color: 'vintagegreen'},
    {id:13, name: 'flannelshirt', color: 'vintagewhite'},
    {id:14, name: 'cordhemd', color: 'black'},
    {id:15, name: 'cordhemd', color: 'vintagebrown'},
    {id:16, name: 'cordhemd', color: 'vintagegreen'},
    {id:17, name: 'basicshirt', color: 'black'},
    {id:18, name: 'basicshirt', color: 'white'}




];
```

here is my simple oberteil.ts

```
export interface Oberteil {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    color : string;
}
```

so now i go into my oberteile.component.ts and initialize oberteil with the const OBERTEILE

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OBERTEILE } from '../oberteil-names';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-oberteile',
  templateUrl: './oberteile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oberteile.component.css']
})
export class OberteileComponent implements OnInit {
  oberteil = OBERTEILE;
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }


}
```

now i want to display them on my oberteile.component.html but i have no access to id

```
<h2>{{oberteil.id}}</h2>
```

i think it is very easy to be solved but i can not find any answers for it, even when i just want to display {{oberteile}}, it just display [object,Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oberteil` is an array of multiple elements. You need to select a specific element of the array, or iterate over the array with `*ngFor`:

```
<h2>{{oberteil[0].id}}</h2><!-- display the ID of the first element -->
<h2 *ngFor="let element of oberteil">{{element.id}}</h2><!-- display IDs of all elements -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`oberteil` is an array. You can't access it like that. You need to specify the index of the array.

Or if you are trying to show the `id` from each element of `oberteil` array, you can use *ngFor directive.

`<h1 *ngFor="let o of oberteil">{{o.id}}</h1>`

See [*ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#listing-items-with-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

oberteil is array, no Object, so you cannot bind the value with `<h2>{{oberteil.id}}</h2>`
It should be like that in *ngFor iteration to get all values

```
<div *ngFor="let item of oberteil">
  <p>{{item.id}}</p>
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <p>{{item.color}}</p>
</div>
```

It is just example to use your oberteil variable in html to bind the data.